# rotating a rectangle around its center?

Tags: algorithm, user-interface, geometry, processing

I want to click and drag a corner of a rectangle, and have the rectangle spin around its center.

This is pretty easy to do with a square:

```
rot = PI * 3 / 4 + atan2( (centerY - mouseY), (centerX - mouseX) );
```

But if I want to rotate a rectangle, I am not sure how to handle the offset to make the rotation smooth as the mouse is moved.

In this jsfiddle example,  http://jsfiddle.net/R4QpV/, clicking on the red corner lets you rotate around the center of the square.  But what if you click on the green corner, there is a jump.  How to make dragging the green corner smooth and follow the mouse as it does when clicking the square's corner?

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/R4QpV/8/, where `mouseDragged()` has been modified. Note: there would be a jump on the red corner in this case.

Answer (score 0):

With a square, the diagonal is along the angle `PI / 4` (or `3*PI/4`) as you have it. With a rectangle, you need to set the rotation based on the angle of the diagonal. I'm not sure exactly what your coordinate system is, but you should replace `PI * 3 / 4` with something like `atan2(centerY - cornerY, centerX - cornerX)` (give or take a +/- sign).